# Unable to use ngGrid - Unknown provider: ngGridProvider

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to include ngGrid into my application, but getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngGridProvider <- ngGrid
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=ngGridProvider%20%3C-%20ngGrid
    at http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3538:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3665:39)
    at http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3543:45
    at getService (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3665:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3687:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3708:23)
    at http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6758:28
    at link (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:897:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:63342/wizard/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6212:13) <div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="wizardApp">

    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>

    <!-- Breeze: -->
    <script src="http://sampleservice.breezejs.com/scripts/q.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/breeze.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.metadata-helper.js"></script>

    <!-- ng-grid: -->

    <script src="bower_components/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-grid/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />

    <!-- the actual app: -->

        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/model.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/datacontext.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/metadataFactory.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/controllers/introductionWizard.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/applicationGeneralWizard.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/applicationTable.js"></script>


        <script src="http://sampleservice.breezejs.com/scripts/ngLogger.js"></script>
        <script  src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.css">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.'s:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('wizardApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'mgo-angular-wizard'
]);

app.value('host', false /*use local host*/ ? "http://localhost:63428" : "http://sampleservice.breezejs.com");

app.controller('ApplicationTableCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope','ngGrid',
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

    }
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',
    ['$scope',  'datacontext','$timeout','WizardHandler','$location',
        function($scope, datacontext, $timeout,WizardHandler,$location) {

            function Customer(name,number,address,contact)
            {
                this.customerName = name;
                this.customerNumber = number;
                this.customerAddress = address;
                this.customerContact = contact;
            }

            console.log('created MainCtrl');
            $scope.items = [];
//            $scope.logList = logger.logList;
//            $scope.lastLog = function(){return logger.lastLog;};

            $scope.step_1_Action = function(name,number){
                 console.log('MainCtrl : step_1_Action dataInput:  ' + name + '  ' + number);

                $scope.currentCustomer = new Customer('','','','');
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerName = name;
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerNumber = number;
                    }
            $scope.step_2_Action = function(address,contact){
                console.log('MainCtrl : step_2_Action dataInput:  ' + address + '   ' + contact);
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerAddress = address;
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerContact = contact;
                    }
            $scope.saveCustomerRecord = function(){
                 datacontext.addCustomer($scope.currentCustomer);
                 datacontext.commit();
                $scope.currentCustomer = new Customer('','','','');
                 //$scope.step1Form.$setPristine();
                 $scope.currentCustomer = {};
                 WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
            }


        }]

);



app
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
        .when('/IntroductionWizard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/Wizards/IntroductionWizard/IntroductionWizard.html',
            controller: 'IntroductionWizardCtrl'
        })
        .when('/ApplicationGeneralWizard', {
            templateUrl: 'views/Wizards/ApplicationGeneralWizard/ApplicationGeneralWizard.html',
            controller: 'ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl'
        })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }).run(
    function ($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.go = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    });

;
```

Here is the ApplicationGeneralWizard.html:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">App Wizard</h3>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Application General Wizard</p>

    <wizard>
        <wz-step title="IntroductionWizard-Step-1">
            <!--<ng-include src=" 'views/Wizards/ApplicationGeneralWizard/ApplicationGeneralWizard-Step-1.html' "></ng-include>-->

            <div class="center">

                <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>


            </div>


        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="IntroductionWizard-Step-2">
            <!--<ng-include src=" 'views/Wizards/IntroductionWizard/IntroductionWizard-Step-2.html' "></ng-include>-->
        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="IntroductionWizard-Step-3">
            <!--<ng-include src=" 'views/Wizards/IntroductionWizard/IntroductionWizard-Step-3.html' "></ng-include>-->
        </wz-step>
    </wizard>

</div>


<div class="footer">

</div>
```

And here is the ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('wizardApp').controller('ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl', ['ngGrid',
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
            console.log('Entering ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl');
    }
]);
```

Here is what the original (developer's) code looks like:

```
<script>
        angular.module('myApp',['ngGrid']);
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngGrid` is a module, not a service. You need to add it to your module's dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module('wizardApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'mgo-angular-wizard',
  'ngGrid'
]);
```

And then remove it from your controller definition so it doesn't try to inject it:

```
angular.module('wizardApp').controller('ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl', 
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
            console.log('Entering ApplicationGeneralWizardCtrl');
    }
);
```